# How to say this more concisely with less redundancy?

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns, redundancy

> I felt like I had a privileged access to something that most people had no access to.

How to say the above more concisely? I feel like the sentence suffers from redundancy. Is it so? I am saying that especially because I used ‘access’ twice.

Comment: This avoids repeating "access" and slightly reduces the word count: "I felt like I had a privileged access to something to which most people had none." I'd also probably eliminate "a".

Comment: I think "privileged" is incorrectly used in your sentence.  / I hate "I felt like" when there's really nothihg there about feelings. / *It seemed as if I had been given access to something that was closed off to most [people].

Comment: "I felt privileged." Or "I felt privileged to have access." If you're privileged, by definition not everyone has access. Unsure if this is on-topic, it seems more like writing advice than grammar.

Comment: Stop trying to avoid "redundancy"!!! 'Redundancy' is often important. You can have no redundancy or you can have clear communication. Which do you want?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on the false premise that the sentence is somehow "suffering" from "redundancy" instead of being enriched and clarified by a rich signal.

Answer (score 4):

"Like" adds nothing special; "access" can be avoided a second time.

- I felt (that) I had a privileged access to something (that) most people are barred from.

Comment: I agree. You can even take it further as the word "privileged" assumes a type of rarity. I felt (that) I had a privileged access to something. Is pretty concise.

Comment: "Privileged" also implies there's some legal barrier for most people, rather than a physical one.  Like classified top secret documents or some such.  If it's just something that's difficult for other people to access for physical reasons, e.g. a nice view from the top of Mt. Everest, an audience with some powerful and reclusive celebrity/politician, etc., you might want to use a different word.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It doesn't have to be legal, it can be technical. E.g. a system administrator may have privileged access to the data on the computers.

Comment: @Barmar True, I guess a better way to put it would be "enforced by manmade rules", whether laws or networking protocols in your case, or whatever.  This would be in contrast to stuff that's simply difficult to access because it's remote and hard to get to, or requires a lot of effort, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think "I had privileged access" is sufficient unless you really want to emphasize the rarity of such access.  The word "privileged" carries the implication that it's not available to most people.